# How can I restore a database to a influxdb container

Tags: database, influxdb, database-restore

Sorry for my ignorance. I have influx db running on docker with docker-compose as below.

```
  influxdb:
   image: influxdb:alpine
   ports:
       - 8086:8086
   volumes:
      - ./influxdb/config/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro
      - ./influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb
```

I need to restore the backup of a database from remote server to this Influxdb container. I have taken the backup as below from remote server.

```
influxd backup -database tech_db /tmp/tech_db
```

I read the documentation and couldn't find a way to restore the DB to docker container.Can anyone give me a pointer to how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had the same issue. Looks like it is impossible because you are not able to kill influxd process in a container.

```
# Restoring a backup requires that influxd is stopped (note that stopping the process kills the container).
docker stop "$CONTAINER_ID"

# Run the restore command in an ephemeral container.
# This affects the previously mounted volume mapped to /var/lib/influxdb.
docker run --rm \
--entrypoint /bin/bash \
-v "$INFLUXDIR":/var/lib/influxdb \
-v "$BACKUPDIR":/backups \
influxdb:1.3 \
-c "influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data -database foo /backups/foo.backup"

# Start the container just like before, and get the new container ID.
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run --rm \
--detach \
-v "$INFLUXDIR":/var/lib/influxdb \
-v "$BACKUPDIR":/backups \
-p 8086 \
influxdb:1.3
)
```

More information is [here](https://gist.github.com/mark-rushakoff/36b4491f97b8781198da36752ecd949b)